# How can i make a path like the number 8 (SpriteKit, Swift)

Tags: swift, path, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a path for an object to follow that is in the shape of the number 8. Is it possible to create a path with curves like the shape of a number 8?

If it's not, how would you suggest I do this?

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
var curve = UIBezierPath()
let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
curve.moveToPoint(startPoint)

// top right
curve.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 250),
  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50),
  controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 250))

// bottom left
curve.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 450),
  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 250),
  controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 450))

// bottom right
curve.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 250),
  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 450),
  controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 250))

// top left
curve.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50),
  controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 250),
  controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50))

curve.closePath()
```

Answer (score 1):

SKPhysicsBody Path Generator is powerful tool that you can create with him what you want!

very comfortable and easy to create your path!

**Basic Instruction**

- Drag and drop the sprite image into drop zone.
- Start drawing path by clicking on coordinates.

[The link](http://mortenjust.com/path-generator/)